# Unable to find storage option in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I just start learning on creating partitions on SQL Server tables with the help of the SQL Server documentation and SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio through wizard

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188730.aspx

When I came to below mentioned step I am unable to find storage option when I right click on my existing tables...

**To create a partitioned table**

> Right-click the table that you wish to partition, point to Storage,
>   and then click Create Partition….

I can able to find storage option under select a page in table properties but there is no option button to select create partition.

So please help me what do I need to do next to create a partition? I already created a filegroup and files as mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions available only in Enterprise edition of SQL Server

List of enabled features for each edition of SQL Serve you may find here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx